# SQLCipher in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, sqlcipher

Is there any proper guideline to use SQLCipher in Ionic 3 application? I am following [this method](https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlcipher-adapter), but having little confusion on where to initialise the db object. Because the Cordova plugin getting detected only on document ready state. ionViewDidLoad is not working as expected.